# What's the real problem behind the "unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled" and how to solve it?

Tags: ssl, openssl

I'm testing a server with the following command:

```
openssl s_client -connect myserver.myhost.com:443
```

And as response I'm receiving:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
80BBF425D37F0000:error:0A000152:SSL routines:final_renegotiate:unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled:../ssl/statem/extensions.c:879:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3058 bytes and written 336 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1687542368
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
---
```

What's the real problem behind myserver.myhost.com that's triggering this error on openssl and how to solve it (in server side, because I know that's not a openssl client problem).

P.S¹: I know that adding 'Options = UnsafeLegacyRenegotiation' will enable openssl client to call this endpoint without problems, but I want to understand the real problem behind and how to solve it.

P.S²: If I try to access the URL directly on browser, it works without any warnings on Google Chrome.

I really appreciate any help

Comment: `New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)`?  SSL is not supported on the port.  No, it's not.  At least not a version that's compatible with your OpenSSL client.  What's your server/configuration?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I don't have access to the server, but I'm trying to understand the problem. I'll add another information on this question. If trying the access the URL directly on browser, it works without any warnings from Chrome.

Comment: What does `openssl version` show?

Comment: @AndrewHenle OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022)

Comment: I'm pretty sure OpenSSL 3.x by default enforces https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5746

Comment: @AndrewHenle I think I understood the problem. The legacy renegotiation isn't allowed by default anymore by openssl, that's the reason for the error.
The RFC5746 defines the new (Secure Renegotiation) and is part of the server configuration accepts or not the Secure Renegotiation. In my case it's not supported as you can see the first question output "Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported".
Is there a "more elegant" way to check if a server is using the the legacy renegotiation instead of just running the command and wait for the error?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Or if enabling "Options = UnsafeLegacyRenegotiation" is there an output that defines the server is using the legacy renegotiation.

Comment: @RanieriMazili: You might consider checking the servers response and look for the `renegotiated_connection` TLS extension as defined [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5746#section-3.2). This is basically what OpenSSL does though when printing *"Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported"* or showing the error.